# Is it legal XML to have two different List<> objects using some sort of level identifier to separate and identify them?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0

I am thinking about using an XML file to hold multiple types of data. Let’s say for this example we have two lists. I see plenty of examples that serializes a single List to an XML root, but I haven’t found the correct keywords to find examples of embedding two.

I’d like to see some C# code that decodes such a structure.

As an example the lists might have classes that look like the following.

```
  public class Item
   {
     public string Name;
     public int Count;
     public bool Active;

     public override string ToString()
     {
       return String.Format("{0,-10} {1,10} {2:True,2:False}", Name, Count, Active);
     }
   }


   public class Item2
   {
     public string Name;
     public string Category;
     public int Length;
     public int Height;

     public override string ToString()
     {
       return Name;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class and put both of your lists inside that class:

```
public class AllTheThings
{
  public List<Item> Items;
  public List<Item2> Items2;
}
```

Then serialize that class.  Also note that you can do this as many levels deep as you want.  For instance  `Item` could have a list inside of it as well.